# I'm getting an authorization error trying to authorize nest integration with home-assistant

Tags: authorization, nest, home-assistant

I'm trying to set up nest integration with HomeAssistant and getting an "Invalid request".
How do I track down the cause?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with the integration at this time. See the note on the Home Assistant Nest Integration page: https://alerts.home-assistant.io/#nest.markdown

For workarounds, check out this github issue: https://github.com/home-assistant/core/issues/67662#issuecomment-1079977875